# How can I take data from an entry box using Tkinter and put that data into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, tkinter

I am taking user input from an entry box (gui widget) and then use a `get_entry()` method to store the data in a variable. I am stuck on how I then get this data into the data frame. I tried to append the data but I was not able to get it to work.

Like I said above I tried to use the append method, but it did not do anything. I can show my code if needed.

Here is the code snippet:

```
#imports 
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk

#creating window 
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Entry Form")
window.geometry("600x600")

#creating pandas dataset
myData = {
    "date":[3], 
    "temperature": [3] 
}
dataFrame = pd.DataFrame(myData)

#methods
def enterbtn():
    date = dateEntry.get()
    temperature = tempEntry.get()
    #dataFrame.add(date, "date")
    new_row = {"date": date, "temperature": temperature}
    dataFrame = dataFrame.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    window.destroy()
    print(dataFrame)



#actual GUIs
tk.Label(window, text = "Please enter a temperature and date, thank 
you!", font = ("Calibri", 20, "bold")).grid(column = 0, row = 0, 
columnspan = 2)
tk.Label(window, text = "Temperature:", font = ("Calibri", 
10)).grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = "e")
tempEntry = tk.Entry(window, font = ("Calibri", 10))
tempEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = "w")
tk.Label(window, text = "Date:", font = ("Calibri", 
10)).grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = "e")
dateEntry = tk.Entry(window, font = ("Calibri", 10))
dateEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = "w")
button1 = tk.Button(window, text = "Enter", font = ("Calibri", 10), 
command = enterbtn)
button1.grid(column = 0, row = 3, columnspan = 2)

#run window
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: `append()` returns a new dataframe, it doesn't modify the df in place. Did you assign the result back to the df variable?

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @nokla I added a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're facing is due to the scope of the dataFrame variable. In your enterbtn function, you're trying to modify the dataFrame variable which is defined outside the function. In Python, if you modify a variable inside a function, it's treated as a new local variable unless you explicitly tell Python you want to use the global variable.
You can solve this by declaring dataFrame as a global variable inside your function. Here's how you can do it:
python

```
def enterbtn():
    global dataFrame
    date = dateEntry.get()
    temperature = tempEntry.get()
    new_row = {"date": date, "temperature": temperature}
    dataFrame = dataFrame.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)
    window.destroy()
    print(dataFrame)
```

By adding the global dataFrame line, you're telling Python that you want to use the dataFrame variable that's defined outside the function. Now, when you modify dataFrame inside the function, it will modify the global variable instead of creating a new local one.

Comment: i'm here for that!

Answer (score 0):

@Gizelly explained correctly the issue with the code provided, but it is generally a [**bad idea**](https://embeddedartistry.com/fieldatlas/the-problems-with-global-variables/) to use `global` variables.

You can pass your `dataFrame` as an argument to the `enterbtn` function:

```python
...

#methods
def enterbtn(df:pd.DataFrame):
    date = dateEntry.get()
    temperature = tempEntry.get()
    new_row = {"date": date, "temperature": temperature}
    df.loc[len(df)] = new_row
    window.destroy()
    print(df)


#actual GUIs
tk.Label(window, text = "Please enter a temperature and date, thank you!", font = ("Calibri", 20, "bold")).grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan = 2)

tk.Label(window, text = "Temperature:", font = ("Calibri", 10)).grid(column = 0, row = 1, sticky = "e")
tempEntry = tk.Entry(window, font = ("Calibri", 10))
tempEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = "w")

tk.Label(window, text = "Date:", font = ("Calibri", 10)).grid(column = 0, row = 2, sticky = "e")
dateEntry = tk.Entry(window, font = ("Calibri", 10))
dateEntry.grid(column = 1, row = 2, sticky = "w")

button1 = tk.Button(window, text = "Enter", font = ("Calibri", 10), command = lambda:enterbtn(df=dataFrame))
button1.grid(column = 0, row = 3, columnspan = 2)

#run window
window.mainloop()
```

- I added `df` as an argument to the function.
- I changed the passed value to the `command` argument in `button1`.
- I replaced the `df.append` with `df.loc` as it was removed in `pandas 2.0`.